# What are nichills?

Tags: meaning

Reading the *Black Book*, a compendium of the iniquities of the governance of England in 1830 (quite a thick tome, I am sorry to have to report), I came across this exposition of the waste in the Exchequer:-

> The exchequer is divided into seven different departments; the
>   tellers, the pells, the king's remembrancers, the lord treasurer's,
>   the auditor's office, the tally court, and the pipe office. The pipe
>   office alone has seven subsidiary absurdities; among these are the
>   clerk of the *nichills*, the clerk of the estreats, and the cursitor
>   baron...

I have managed to run down most of this but cannot find a definition for *nichills*; there is one [here](http://thelawdictionary.org/nichills/) but it is cut off, and requires a subscription for the rest. So, does anyone know what *nichills* are?

Comment: The link you provide comes from a book, and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ip9AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=nichills+debts&source=bl&ots=VT2rAse8-d&sig=FSFDE1dyq9I3dUUVhFDLxqTzsRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7c36gcHLAhXmnIMKHXAKDdoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=nichills%20debts&f=false) has the full version.

Comment: I'm looking for a thin tome. Guess this isn't it.

Comment: Was it a 19th century nighttime cold medicine, perhaps?

Comment: There's some definition in the link provided by cobaltduck.

Comment: @cobaltduck, how do I get to read that?

Comment: [*OED 1* s.v. **Nichil**](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/n961/mode/2up).

Comment: Yep, StoneyB's got it.

Comment: @BrianHooper: If my link does not work for you, I apologize.  Try from a different computer/ device.  After that, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the reference indicated by StoneyB above -- [The New English Dictionary on Historical Principles](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/n961/mode/2up):

> **Nichil,** *sb,* *obs.*
>
> 1. Nothing, naught.
> 2. *Law.* The return made by the sheriff to the exchequer in cases where the party named in the writ had no goods upon which a levy could
>      be made.
>
>    b. *Clerk of the Nichils,* a clerk of the exchequer who made
>      note of the nichils returned by the sheriff.

(Extraneous details omitted.)

There is also a verb defined, equally indecipherable.